# Install two different versions of MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

My problem is the same that this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253777/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-versions-of-mysql-workbench

I need to use mysql workbench 8 for mysql server version 8.0.27 and mysql workbench 6 for a version 5 mysql server.

The problem is that when installing workbench 8 it deletes existing workbench with lower version.
I've tried to install Workbench6 on a completely different location to see if the installation does not find it but I it finds it anyway.

Also tried to install a 32 bit version of workbench 6 but again, version 8 delete it when installing.

Found some comments saying to enable multiple instances in menu -> edit -> preferences -> others, but this is only to open multiple instances of the same version.

I've looked for a portable version of workbench 6 but had no luck.
I don't understand why this problem is not having an answer by MySQL, even the MySQL forum doesnt have a solution or even an explanation why this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I use a Vm for that porpose. where an "old 5.7.xx is installed alongside a workbench 6.3that work with that well, because the newer version don't do.

You can use for that purpose also a linux server as vm not only windows

Comment: That was also my last resource but it is a over do.

Comment: there is no other solution, so use it

Comment: Found a portable version of Workbench 5.2.47. I've upload it to my [github](https://github.com/joaordsoares/MySQL-Workbench5.2.47CE-Portable.git)

Answer (score 0):

Found a portable version of Workbench 5.2.47. I've upload it to my [github](https://github.com/joaordsoares/MySQL-Workbench5.2.47CE-Portable.git).

Although I use this software with no problems until now, this is not from my authorship, use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest zip archive (version 6.3.8 and earlier has it) from here: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/
Look out because x64 archive wasn't working in my case but 32bit works fine.
Unzip to different folder and that's it.